# Extracting ESR and ESL values from capacitor plot

Tags: capacitor

There is a capacitor called CL21A106KOQNNN. 
I want to make an RLC model of this capacitor. 
Zc=1/(jwc) 
Zc=jwL 
There are these formulas above, how do I extract from the plot properly the ESR and ESL of the capacitor?

https://weblib.samsungsem.com/mlcc/mlcc-ec-data-sheet.do?partNumber=CL21A106KOQNNN
[image]

Comment: ESR is given by the blue trace on the chart. You just read it off the chart (yes, that means ESR is frequency-dependent). If that doesn't answer the ESR part of your question, please edit the question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

ESR is given by the blue trace on the chart. You just read it off the chart. Yes, that means ESR is frequency-dependent. If you want to reduce the model to use a single fixed value for ESR, then use the value for your operating frequency. If operating frequency is variable, then I often use the value at resonance, since it's at resonance that the ESR has the most effect in determining the impedance (Z) of the capacitor, but for some applications another choice might be more suitable.

If you aren't given the blue chart, then the ESR at resonance is equal to \$|Z|\$ at resonance. That is, the minimum value of \$|Z|\$ on the chart is equal to the ESR at the resonant frequency.

ESL is also somewhat dependent on frequency, and some of the vendors' online tools will provide that chart directly as well. If you are working with a vendor who doesn't provide it, the easiest way to determine a useful estimate of the ESL is to estimate the resonant frequency from the chart and use the formula for resonance of a series LC circuit:
$$\omega_r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$
or
$$L=\frac{1}{\omega_r^2 C}$$
remembering to convert the frequency on the chart to radian frequency for your calculation by \$\omega=2\pi f\$.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic (first order) RLC model, you read them off the plot.  C is given by the falling left-to-middle asymptote.  L by the rising middle-to-right asymptote.  R is the value at the valley (where X<sub>C</sub> = X<sub>L</sub>).  And that's it, you're done, you have a model that is most accurate near resonance, that represents the overall magnitude impedance well enough, but misses ESR(F) dependency, and any quirks (like the bump just above resonance, or the one in the GHz).

To increase ESR at low frequencies, you need a more developed network -- more terms in the equation.

In general, you can do this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/677869/311631

Note that complexity of the (RLC lumped element) circuit directly corresponds to the order of rational polynomial expressing the transfer function (for some value of "complexity"), so to express a more complex function (such as capturing the losses at LF), you need a larger circuit.

I don't happen to have any handy examples to illustrate for capacitors directly, but *just for flavor* (this is not the answer, this is a hint at the form the answer will take), here's one I made of an inductive component:

```
* 2643000101
* Fair-Rite Corporation
* Loose Ferrite Bead
* 40 Ohms (Z @ 100MHz)
* I Sat Approx. 800mA (-3dB)
*
* Curve Fit by Tim Williams, 2017-05-09
*
.SUBCKT FB_2643000101 1 2
R2 1 3 0.001
R1 1 4 20
C  4 2 1.22p
L  3 2 0.41u
Rs1 3 5 32
Ls1 2 5 0.67u
Rs2 3 6 33.8
Ls2 2 6 143n
Rs3 3 7 46.4
Ls3 7 8 18.83n
Cs3 2 8 113.2p

.ENDS
```

<sup>Source: [own work](https://seventransistorlabs.com/Modeling) | [FB_2643000101.ckt](https://seventransistorlabs.com/Modeling/SPICE/FB_2643000101.ckt) | Reference: [2643000101 Datasheet](https://fair-rite.com/product/emi-suppression-beads-2643000101/)</sup>

[As you're interested in modeling, I'm assuming a netlist will be meaningful. Perhaps that's an over-ambitious assumption.]

The circuit for a capacitor will look similar, with Ls swapped for Cs of course, and swapping parallel/series arrangement.

When ESR follows a parallel asymptote, it's actually that the approximation follows a geometric series, with the number of terms determining the frequency range and fitness, and the ratio between terms determining the exponent (note that the |Z| curve is *very slightly shallower* than 1/f; this is a consequence of the loss, per Kramers–Kronig relations).  This tip can be developed into a generalized distributed loss model, or simply used as a starting point for further adjustment of parameters.  (The above model was simply hand-tuned, comparing modeled impedance to datasheet curves.  An algorithmic solution would be preferred if you need to model dozens, or hundreds even, of parameters, to high accuracy.  These are available in some RF design tools.)